# Avoid the preprocess/hook function defined from the Zen theme is called for its sub-theme

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

We are using a theme that inherits from the Zen theme. the Zen theme implements `zen_process_html_tag()` and `zen_html_head_alter()`, and we want these functions not to be called; we tried to override these functions in our theme, but then Drupal call zen's functions first, then the functions in our theme.

How can I avoid this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Those are part of HTML5 support bundled with Zen 7.x-5.x. Your options are either downgrading to Zen 7.x-3.x or patching Zen. Please [open an issue](http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/zen) at Zen's issue queue asking to provide an option to turn on or off the header manipulation.

Comment: Meaning: you can't prevent it from being called unless you patch Zen. There might be some way to do it with hook_theme_registry_alter, but it will require building a module for that and it might just not be worth the hassle. The Drupal Way (tm) is advertised as "hook, don't patch" but it actually starts with "take and give contributions as often as possible."